# R plotly separate functional legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I want to produce a plot via R plotly with independent legends while respecting the colorscale.

This is what I have:

```r
library(plotly)

X <- data.frame(xcoord = 1:6,
                ycoord = 1:6,
                score  = 1:6,
                gender = c("M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F"),
                age = c("young", "old", "old", "old", "young", "young"))

plot_ly(data = X, x = ~xcoord, y = ~ycoord, split = ~interaction(age, gender),
        type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
        marker = list(color = ~score,
                      colorbar = list(len = .5, y = .3)))
```

This is the outcome:
[image: outcome]

As you can see, the colorbar is messed up and the two categories are entangled.

I need to have separate legends for `age` (young vs old) and `gender` (M vs F), that can be clicked independently from one another. This would be the expected outcome:
[image: expected outcome]

---

**Edit 1**
This is the equivalent with `ggplot2`:

```r
gg <- ggplot(X, aes(x = xcoord, y = ycoord)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = score, shape = gender, alpha = age), size = 5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("M" = 19, "F" = 19)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("young" = 1, "old" = 1))

ggplotly(gg)
```

It does display correctly in ggplot, but breaks when applying `ggplotly()`.

Please note that I would favor a solution with the native `plotly` plot, rather than a *post hoc* `ggplotly()` fix as has been proposed in other posts.

---

**Edit 2**
Although the current answers do disentangle the two legends (`age` and `gender`), they are not functional. For instance, if you click on the `young` level, the whole `age` legend will be toggled on/off. The objective here is that each sub level of each legend can be toggled independently from the others, and that by clicking on the legend's levels, the dot will show/hide accordingly.

Comment: I tried setting a common `coloraxis` in the `layout` according to https://plotly.com/r/colorscales/#share-color-axis ; while it works with the heatmap example, `plot_ly` throws a warning that this attribute does not apply to scatter[plot] objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plotly does not seem to easily support this, since different guides are linked to multiple traces. So deselecting e.g. "old" on an "Age" trace will not remove anything from the separate set of points from the "Gender" trace.

This is a workaround using `crosstalk` and a `SharedData` data object. Instead of (de)selecting plotly traces, this uses filters on the dataset that is used by plotly. It technically achieves the selection behaviour that is requested, but whether or not it is a working solution depends on the final application. There are likely ways to adjust the styling and layout to make it more plotly-ish, if the mechanism works for you.

```
library(crosstalk)

#SharedData object used for filters and plot
shared <- SharedData$new(X) 

crosstalk::bscols(
  widths = c(2, 10),
   list(
     crosstalk::filter_checkbox("Age", 
                                label = "Age",
                                sharedData = shared, 
                                group = ~age),
     crosstalk::filter_checkbox("Gender", 
                                label = "Gender",
                                sharedData = shared, 
                                group = ~gender)
   ),
   plot_ly(data = shared, x = ~xcoord, y = ~ycoord,
           type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
           marker = list(color = ~score,
                         colorbar = list(len = .5, y = .3),
                         cmin = 0, cmax = 6)) %>%
    layout(
      xaxis = list(range=c(.5,6.5)),
      yaxis = list(range=c(.5,6.5))
    )
   )
```

[image]

#### Edit: initialize all checkboxes as "checked"

I only managed to do this by modifying the output HTML tags. This produces the same plot, but has all boxes checked at the beginning.

```
out <- crosstalk::bscols(...) #previous output object

library(htmltools)
out_tags <- htmltools::renderTags(out)

#check all Age and Gender checkboxes
out_tags$html <- stringr::str_replace_all(
  out_tags$html, 
  '(<input type="checkbox" name="(Age|Gender)" value=".*")/>',
  '\\1 checked="checked"/>'
)
out_tags$html <- HTML(out_tags$html)
# view in RStudio Viewer
browsable(as.tags(out_tags))
#or from Rmd chunk
as.tags(out_tags)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this does work as intended! Do you know if it is possible to have all the checkboxes 'checked' by default? Feels a bit weird that when the graph is initialized none of the boxes are checked, yet all the data is displayed. Also, when every box is uncheck, there are still some data points data shows up.

Comment: Yes, some of that behaviour feels strange. I'll add some code that pre-checks all box, but only via modifying the output HTML object... And apparently unchecking everything does not trigger re-rendering, so the most recently selected points remain on the plot. If solutions outside of pure plotly are a viable option, then a shiny input element with an plotly output should resolve those issues.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for. I was able to create a meaningful color bar, though.

I removed the call for interaction between the groups and created a separate trace. Then I created legend groups and named them to create separate legends for `gender` and `age`. When I pull `color =` out of the call to create a colorbar, this synced the color scales.

However, it assigns colors to the labels for age and gender and that's not meaningful! There are a few things that don't line up with your request, but someone may be able to build on this information.

```
plot_ly(data = X, x = ~xcoord, y = ~ycoord, 
        split = ~age,
        legendgroup = 'age', # create first split and name it
        legendgrouptitle = list(text = "Age"),
        type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
        color = ~score,
        marker = list(colorbar = list(len = .5, y = .3))) %>% 
  add_trace(split = ~gender,
            legendgroup = 'gender', # create second split and name it
            color = ~score,
            legendgrouptitle = list(text = "Gender")) %>% 
    colorbar(title = 'Score')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. We are getting closer to the solution. The main problem is (like the answer above), I need the levels of each legend to be clickable. For instance, I want to be able to click on `old` to only show/hide participants that are old. Same for `gender`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want. I tried to made the legends for age and gender using two `markers`. The legends are independently clickable, but I am not sure if this is the way you want them to have clickable. It is also possible to click on the colorbar. You can use this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
plot_ly() %>%
  add_markers(data = X,
            x = ~xcoord, 
            y = ~ycoord, 
            type = "scatter", 
            mode = "markers",
            #name = "M",
            color = I("grey"),
            split = ~gender,
            legendgroup = 'gender', 
            legendgrouptitle = list(text = "Gender")) %>%
  add_markers(data = X,
              x = ~xcoord, 
              y = ~ycoord, 
              type = "scatter", 
              mode = "markers",
              #name = "M",
              color = I("grey"),
              split = ~age,
              legendgroup = 'age', 
              legendgrouptitle = list(text = "Age")) %>%
  add_trace(data = X,
            x = ~xcoord, 
            y = ~ycoord, 
            type = "scatter", 
            mode = "markers",
            name = "",
            marker = list(color = ~score,
                          colorbar = list(len = .5, y = .3)))
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, I need the levels of each legend to be clickable. For instance, I want to be able to click on `old` to only show/hide participants that are old. Same for `gender`.